# Autofocus when clicking button to new page (seperate html)

Tags: html, angularjs, autofocus

I was able to implement auto-focus when you click a button taking you to the modal. Due to the following code:

AngularJS:

```
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" auto-focus>
```

However when applying the same logic to input boxes that are available after clicking on a button and going to a separate page, it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone encountered this before or experienced the same issue?

Comment: Oh sorry, so another route. Not a modal, not the same page but a little different or refresh. A completely separate page.

Comment: Just one auto-focus element? No contention?

Comment: Yes it works fine regarding modals just not this one.

Comment: Just for clarification -- are you hiding then showing boxes after a button click? If so the focus would be on the clicked button and you'd need JS to change the focus to the `input` either inside the `ng-click`

Comment: Yes it would be a separate page so the original button is gone, if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the built in `autofocus` like this

```
<input ... autofocus="{{$index==0}}"/>
```

Have you tried that? No custom directive.

Comment: Is that for html? AngularJS? Sorry new so a bit unsure where that would be placed.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: Try seeing which element has the focus. You can `console.log(document.querySelector(":focus"));`